# Logging the Correct time using java simpledateformat

Tags: java, date, logging

I've been looking around for a couple of days, I think I have the answer.
I don't have a lot of experience with java, so I wanted a second, or more, opinion.
Anyway the issue my logging function started logging the wrong time after DST started:

```
  private static void logmsg( String lfile, String msg) {
try {
    Date date = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd HHmm");
    String formattedDate = sdf.format(date);
    PrintStream fubar = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(lfile, true));
    fubar.print(formattedDate+": "+msg+"\n");
    fubar.close();
} catch(Exception e2) {
    e2.printStackTrace();   // gotta print if logging won't work.
}
```

}

I spent a fair amount of time here, and elsewhere, looking for a simple answer. I think this is it, and I wanted it where I could find it again. :)

```
  private static void logmsg( String lfile, String msg) {
try {
    Date date = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + TimeZone.getDefault().getDSTSavings());
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd HHmm");
    String formattedDate = sdf.format(date);
    PrintStream fubar = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(lfile, true));
    fubar.print(formattedDate+": "+msg+"\n");
    fubar.close();
} catch(Exception e2) {
    e2.printStackTrace();   // gotta print if logging won't work.
}
}
```

Basically changing the `Date()` initialization to get the system time and add the default timezone offset in millis. Am I overlooking some gotcha?

All I needed was a simple, accurate, local timestamp in a file.
The same file is written by a pl/sql function that is part of the overall process, I initially noticed when the java datestamps were out of sequence with the rest.

Comment: Ok, I finally figured out the issue. The java I have to use for this project dates from before they changed the DST rules in 2005. So I happened to work on this issue in the few weeks before Apr 6 this year, after DST actually started. Running my test program on my desktop's version of java gives the expected results. My "fix" causing the time to be an hour off in the other direction.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at java.util.Calendar and GregorianCalendar classes
Calendar c= Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault(), Locale.ENGLISH);

Comment: My problem may stem from an old Java (installed with Oracle 9i) but when I try `System.out.println(c.getTime());` I still get `Tue Apr 01 14:13:41 CST 2014` When it should be `Tue Apr 01 15:13:41 CDT 2014`